# Criar expressões em strings

Tags: javascript, string, expressões

Suponhamos que eu tenha a seguinte string:

```
const str = `Eu sou

@if (1 + 1 === 2):
  um dois
@endif

!`;
```

Como faço para poder executar expressões como aquele `if`?
Não quero uma solução exatamente para aquele problema, apenas a forma correta de se fazê-lo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo,

Já que você usa `const` então você pode fazer algo assim:

```
const str = `Eu sou ${1 + 1 === 2 ? 'um dois' : 'nao sou'}!`;
```

Em outros casos mais avançados eu recomendo você usar alguma linguagem de template em JS como o Handlebars.js - https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Também não resolve o meu problema. Quero saber como fazer aquilo (trecho de código acima) funcionar...

Comment: Amigo, aquele trecho de código não é Javascript, não existe essa sintaxe \@if nem \@endif em Javascript, não têm como funcionar. Vais ter que adaptar teu "trecho" de código para algo que o JavaScript entenda OU adaptar para alguma linguagem de template tipo handlebars.

Comment: Pois é. O Handlebars também não era uma "linguagem" até ser escrito. Basicamente, o que quero fazer é criar um tipo de engine de visualização (view engine) e gostaria de saber como interpretar as expressões (como um `if`) que se encontram numa string (como no "trecho" que forneci acima).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Essa função avalia códigos javascript armazenados em string.

No seu caso:

```js
const str = 'if (1 + 1 === 2) {alert(\'um dois\');}';

eval(str);
```

Comment: O trecho de código não funcionou. Um erro foi lançado.

Comment: É porque o seu código está dando erro. Atualizei com um código javascript que faz um alert.